# How can I add my application's shortcut to the homescreen like the one of 360 security

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create my app's shortcut/launcher icon on the homescreen like the one of 360 security and  release an  activity when user click's on the icon without entering in the app

Comment: This is your first question posted here and I wanted to try and provide you a little feedback.  First, I can't be sure why others voted your question down, but normally a question must meet the scope of the question site, which this one probably does not, and also it should show that you've put some work into this, looking for a solution, and saying what you have already tried.  Also I think you might want to more fully describe your question, as it's often hard for someone to see what you're working with.  It would be good to edit your Q and say what versions you're using.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void addShortcut() {

    //Adding shortcut for MainActivity
    //on Home screen
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Constants.DEVICE_NO, mDevice.getFDeviceNo());
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, mDevice.getFName());
    int defaultImageRes = Utils.getDeviceImage(mDevice.getFViewType());
    int color = Color.RED;
    Bitmap defaultBitmap = overlay(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), defaultImageRes), color);
    if (mDevice.isCustomImage() && !mDevice.getFImage().isEmpty()) {
        File file = MyApplication.getImageLoader(this).getDiskCache().get(ImageUtils.getImageUrl(mDevice.getFImageName()));
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (bitmap != null) {
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 128, 128, true);
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, scaledBitmap);
        } else {
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, defaultBitmap);
        }
    } else {
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, defaultBitmap);
    }

    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.added_to_home_screen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```